# Concat Results of 2 Select Queries into 1 Column (oracle)

Tags: oracle

Im trying to insert a record into my table. But there is 1 column in which I want to get concatenated results of 2 select statements. Like the 2 statements will fetch their records and concatenate to form 1 value so that it can be inserted into the column.

```
insert into ABC (Name,City,Age) 
 Values ('John',(
           (Select City from TableA where ID=1)concat(Select City from TableA where ID=2)),'22')
```

Or it can be comma separated but I am not getting what to use here.

Comment: what is your platform ? MYSQL - ORACLE ?

Comment: I m using ORACLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    INSERT INTO ABC (Name, City, Age)
         VALUES ('John',
                 ( 
                   (SELECT City FROM TableA WHERE ID = 1) || 
                   (SELECT City FROM TableA WHERE ID = 2)
                 ),
                 '22');
```

But ensure   ... WHERE ID = 1 and ....WHERE ID = 2 return one row.

Comment: Thanks , this worked my friend. I tried this on w3schools  but not sure it will work with oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Using a cross join to select from the two tables produces a nice clear statement:

```
insert into ABC (Name,City,Age) 
select 'John', concat(t1.city, t2.city), 22
from TableA t1
     cross join TableA t2
where t1.ID = 1
and t2.ID = 2
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CONCAT() or CONCAT_WS() functions for this ([reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat))

```
insert into ABC (Name,City,Age) Values (
  'John', 
  CONCAT_WS(' ', (Select City from TableA where ID=1), (Select City from TableA where ID=2)),
  '22'
 )
```

Comment: @ArsalanSherwani what error did you get? can you run both of queries from TableA separately to be sure there is only one record in result? you can also add 'limit 1' at the end of "Select City from TableA where ID=1" for this.

Comment: Oracle RDBMS doesn't have a `concat_ws` function. The doc you linked to is for MySQL, a different Oracle-owned product.